sysfs:duplicate .plt under /sys/modules
My system: aarch64
Kernel version: linux-4.19
I changed my gcc from 7.3.0 to 10.3.1 and recompiled kernel code.
After new kernel installed and rebooted, some call trace printed in dmesg as below:
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel: sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/module/virtio/sections/.plt'
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel: CPU: 94 PID: 831 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 4.19.90.rc1.aarch64 #1
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel: Hardware name: QEMU KVM Virtual Machine, BIOS 0.0.0 02/06/2015
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel: Call trace:
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x190
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  show_stack+0x28/0x34
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  dump_stack+0xa4/0xe8
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  sysfs_warn_dup+0x70/0x90
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  sysfs_add_file_mode_ns+0x19c/0x1d0
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  create_files+0xa8/0x200
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  internal_create_group+0x178/0x210
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  sysfs_create_group+0x30/0x40
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  add_sect_attrs+0x174/0x200
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  mod_sysfs_setup+0x1e8/0x210
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  load_module+0x46c/0x820
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  __se_sys_finit_module+0xb8/0x120
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  __arm64_sys_finit_module+0x28/0x34
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  el0_svc_common+0x7c/0x134
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  el0_svc_handler+0x3c/0x7c
Jul 10 15:39:59 localhost kernel:  el0_svc+0x8/0x1f8

In fact, it seemed that all kernel modules met the problem "cannot create duplicate filename .plt"，which causes directory "sections" doesn't exist any more under /sys/modules/.Meanwhile all the modules installed successfully,and the system works fine so far.
As a test, I wrote a simple module like:
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
MODULE_AUTHOR("qink");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Test elf plt");

static __init int test_plt_init(void)
{
    printk("Inset a new test module.\n");
    return 0;
}

static __exit void test_plt_exit(void)
{
    printk("New test module exits.\n");
}

module_init(test_plt_init);
module_exit(test_plt_exit);

My makefile is like:
obj-m :=test_plt.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD :=$(shell pwd)  
modules :  
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean :  
        rm -f *.o .*.cmd *.symvers

And I compiled with gcc 10.3.1 and insmod it, the same message showed again, while I did the same thing on a gcc 7.3.0 system and there was no such message.
Since it seemed like a problem with somthing called ".plt", I used readelf -S to see what is is.
The result with module test_plt.ko compiled with gcc 7.3.0:
There are 37 section headers, starting at offset 0x2a910:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE             0000000000000000  00000040
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000064
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     1
  [ 3] .init.text        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000064
       0000000000000028  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [ 4] .rela.init.text   RELA             0000000000000000  00017278
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018   I      34     3     8
  [ 5] .exit.text        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000008c
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [ 6] .rela.exit.text   RELA             0000000000000000  000172d8
       0000000000000048  0000000000000018   I      34     5     8
  [ 7] .modinfo          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000a8
       00000000000000ce  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [ 8] .rodata.str1.8    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000178
       0000000000000038  0000000000000001 AMS       0     0     8
  [ 9] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000001b0
       000000000000005c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [10] .rela.eh_frame    RELA             0000000000000000  00017320
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   I      34     9     8
  [11] __mcount_loc      PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000210
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [12] .rela__mcount_loc RELA             0000000000000000  00017350
       0000000000000018  0000000000000018   I      34    11     8
  [13] .note.Linux       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000218
       0000000000000018  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [14] __versions        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000230
       00000000000000c0  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [15] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000002f0
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [16] .gnu.linkonce.thi PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000300
       0000000000000380  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
  [17] .rela.gnu.linkonc RELA             0000000000000000  00017368
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   I      34    16     8
  [18] .plt              NOBITS           0000000000000380  00000680
       0000000000000001  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [19] .init.plt         NOBITS           0000000000000381  00000680
       0000000000000001  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [20] .text.ftrace_tram NOBITS           0000000000000382  00000680
       0000000000000001  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [21] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000000000  00000680
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [22] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000680
       000000000000bb4a  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [23] .rela.debug_info  RELA             0000000000000000  00017398
       0000000000013320  0000000000000018   I      34    22     8
  [24] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000c1ca
       0000000000000900  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [25] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000caca
       0000000000000060  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [26] .rela.debug_arang RELA             0000000000000000  0002a6b8
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018   I      34    25     8
  [27] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000cb2a
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [28] .rela.debug_range RELA             0000000000000000  0002a718
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018   I      34    27     8
  [29] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000cb5a
       0000000000000c5f  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [30] .rela.debug_line  RELA             0000000000000000  0002a778
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   I      34    29     8
  [31] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000d7b9
       0000000000009478  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [32] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00016c31
       0000000000000024  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [33] .note.GNU-stack   PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00016c55
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [34] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00016c58
       00000000000004e0  0000000000000018          35    47     8
  [35] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00017138
       0000000000000139  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [36] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  0002a7a8
       0000000000000165  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)


The result with module test_plt.ko compiled with gcc 10.3.1:
There are 39 section headers, starting at offset 0xb8f0:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .note.gnu.bu[...] NOTE             0000000000000000  00000040
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 2] .note.Linux       NOTE             0000000000000000  00000064
       0000000000000018  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000007c
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     1
  [ 4] .init.text        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000007c
       000000000000002c  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [ 5] .rela.init.text   RELA             0000000000000000  00006b48
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018   I      36     4     8
  [ 6] .exit.text        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000a8
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [ 7] .rela.exit.text   RELA             0000000000000000  00006ba8
       0000000000000048  0000000000000018   I      36     6     8
  [ 8] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000c4
       0000000000000001  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     1
  [ 9] .rodata.str1.8    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000c8
       0000000000000038  0000000000000001 AMS       0     0     8
  [10] .modinfo          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000100
       00000000000000d2  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [11] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000001d8
       0000000000000054  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [12] .rela.eh_frame    RELA             0000000000000000  00006bf0
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   I      36    11     8
  [13] __mcount_loc      PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000230
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [14] .rela__mcount_loc RELA             0000000000000000  00006c20
       0000000000000018  0000000000000018   I      36    13     8
  [15] __versions        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000238
       00000000000000c0  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [16] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000002f8
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [17] .gnu.linkonc[...] PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000300
       0000000000000380  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
  [18] .rela.gnu.li[...] RELA             0000000000000000  00006c38
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   I      36    17     8
  [19] .plt.idx          PROGBITS         0000000000000380  00000680
       0000000000000001  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [20] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000000381  00000681
       0000000000000001  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     1
  [21] .init.plt         NOBITS           0000000000000382  00000682
       0000000000000001  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [22] .text.ftrace[...] PROGBITS         0000000000000383  00000682
       0000000000000001  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     1
  [23] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000000000  00000683
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [24] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000683
       0000000000002bbb  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [25] .rela.debug_info  RELA             0000000000000000  00006c68
       0000000000004a28  0000000000000018   I      36    24     8
  [26] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000323e
       0000000000000511  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [27] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000374f
       0000000000000060  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [28] .rela.debug_[...] RELA             0000000000000000  0000b690
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018   I      36    27     8
  [29] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000037af
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [30] .rela.debug_[...] RELA             0000000000000000  0000b6f0
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018   I      36    29     8
  [31] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000037df
       0000000000000448  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [32] .rela.debug_line  RELA             0000000000000000  0000b750
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   I      36    31     8
  [33] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00003c27
       00000000000028a9  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [34] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000064d0
       0000000000000026  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [35] .note.GNU-stack   PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000064f6
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [36] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  000064f8
       0000000000000510  0000000000000018          37    49     8
  [37] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00006a08
       0000000000000139  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [38] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  0000b780
       000000000000016e  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), p (processor specific)

It does show that .plt becomes two, I suppose this is the reason why kernel detect multi .plt in load_module and remove directory "sections".
gcc version for 7.3.0:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --without-isl --without-cloog --enable-gnu-indirect-function --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --with-stage1-ldflags=' -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now' --with-boot-ldflags=' -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now' --with-multilib-list=lp64
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC) 

gcc version for 10.3.1:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/10.3.1/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl --without-cloog --enable-gnu-indirect-function --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --with-stage1-ldflags=' -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now' --with-boot-ldflags=' -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now' --disable-bootstrap --with-multilib-list=lp64 --enable-bolt
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.3.1 (GCC)

Now I wonder that does this matter with gcc? Is there any gcc option I can use to avoid it? What are the effects if "sections" doesn't exist under /sys/modules?
